# Testing the Java methods through the JMeter

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, jmeter, postman

My problem - we have a utility jar containing the java methods that expects a payload from other groups and invokes rest endpoints then finally some data gets persisted in database. I want to test the Java methods to ascertain that Java methods are invoking right APIs and correct data persists in the database. I covered individual APIs validations through the Postman but want to ensure this flow as well as I cannot wait till consumers develop their services and test this flow. These methods are implemented by consumer services by adding a JAR file as a Maven dependency in their project and subsequently creating instances of the objects as needed.

I know that JMeter can be used to test Java methods through Java sampler requests but very less information I could find out on this subject.

Will be great if someone can share their thought on this subject through their experiences and how to achieve it.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Update - I have tried some ideas like the ones suggested by Dmitri but it did not really work out as its not an executable JAR.

Comment: JMeter is for load testing, you wouldn't normally use it to verify correctness… your use case sounds like it could be easily done with the help of Spring Boot's standard tools. Did you try that? You could use something like [WireMock](https://wiremock.org/) to mock the REST endpoints during tests.

Comment: Yes that's correct, Jmeter is for performance test but we wanted to check workflow where we call the java methods that invoke the APIs and verify the database entries- all in whole. JMeter does provide these facilities and we can use that for our function checks and increase the number of threads to convert the same into performance tests. I will check out the WireMock and if I can use it somehow as I am still stuck on this query.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: updated as reqired

Comment: voting to close - this is not an answerable question as it's not clear what you really want and I'm not sure you know either. in some parts you talk about utility jar, sometimes about spring boot app, sometimes methods with tokens which actually would maybe be apis...

Comment: I tried to provide all the information available and all of that is very much correct, just now removed some information to keep it clear so that focus is not lost.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a .jar file exposing some [public methods](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_modifiers.asp) you could:

1. Add the .jar file to [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath)
2. Restart JMeter to pick it up
3. Add [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) to your Test plan
4. Invoke your method from [Groovy code](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black).

For example if you have the following Utility class:

```
package com.example;

public class UtilityClass {

    public String hello(String name) {
        return "Hello, " + name;
    }
}
```

If you package it into .jar and add it to JMeter Classpath you can invoke the `hello()` function from JMeter as follows:

```
import com.example.UtilityClass

UtilityClass utilityClass = new UtilityClass()

String helloFunctionResponse = utilityClass.hello("lonelyLearner")

log.info("Got response from the utility class: " + helloFunctionResponse)
```

Demo:

[image]

Once done you implement the utility functions invocation logic you can add the JDBC Driver .jar to JMeter classpath and check the database using [JDBC Connection Configuration and JDBC Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-db-test-plan.html) sampler.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, unfortunately ours is a Spring boot app and it requires Autowiring details from other teams' methods. We tried the solution you provided but its throwing some errors related to Java Timemodule which is used in other groups' java methods and we are not sure how to get those details programmtically.

Comment: In this case you can package the application as an [executable .jar](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/executable-jar.html) and run it using [OS Process Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-external-commands-and-programs-locally-and-remotely-jmeter)

Comment: oh sure, I am going to try this out and will update you back. It may take a while for me to figure out OS Sampler but will do it and update you for sure

Comment: Update - It did not work out either, the methods in the app actually need some token sort of information from consumers of this particular service and entering that manually also did not work out. Any other idea you may have ?

Comment: plus this jar is going to be added as a dependency and while creating the executable jar it needs a main class which is not there as it has an interface. So its failing there. :(